# NTWCO Dataset in Survival Analysis explanation?

Tags: r, statistics, survival-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaAAW.png)I am currently working on a research project in survival analysis & I came across this dataset - https://rdrr.io/cran/survival/man/nwtco.html, which is pretty useful for my research. However, I am not able to understand the variables in this dataset, as it is heavily inclined towards the medical field.

Can someone please explain the variables?

"","seqno","instit","histol","stage","study","rel","edrel","age","in.subcohort"
"1",1,2,2,1,3,0,6075,25,FALSE

"2",2,1,1,2,3,0,4121,50,FALSE

"3",3,2,2,1,3,0,6069,9,FALSE

"4",4,2,1,4,3,0,6200,28,TRUE

"5",5,2,2,2,3,0,1244,55,FALSE

"6",6,1,1,2,3,0,2932,32,FALSE

"7",7,1,1,4,3,1,324,45,FALSE

"8",8,1,1,2,3,0,5408,44,FALSE

"9",9,1,1,1,3,0,5215,123,FALSE

"10",10,2,1,2,3,0,1381,31,FALSE

Comment: you need to use google to look them up ... I don't say that to be funny but if this is a research project doing your own background reading will be invaluable to you.

Comment: I did look up. But still not able to find anyone else working on it. There was a publication on this dataset but that also used a modified version of it. The one included in the R package seems to be different.

Comment: did you use google to understand the variables in the dataset you mention in your original question?

Comment: yup I did. Couldn't find any working project/analysis on it. My main concern is about the histology of institution/lab. These 2 columns, what are they exactly specifying? Rest is fine.

Comment: the columns are talking about two different sources of the results one from a local laboratory the other result from a central laboratory.

Comment: Both of these take the values of 1 & 2. So if one of them is 1 & the other is 2 & vice versa, what does it mean? Thats the main confusion for me actually.

Comment: Can you print the head of the dataframe and post it in your question.  I can't find the download link.

Comment: Hey ,I have added the link in the updated question. Please do check it. Thanks

Comment: I did check it, it doesn't provide a link to the raw data just a description of the data.  Can you put the first ten lines of the raw data on your question.

Comment: I have added the first 10 lines of the raw data. Please see if its understandable

Comment: OK.  I see the sample, I see your point.  It isn't clear what the 1 or 2 numbers represent.  Conventionally, when you have a boolean result 1 is TRUE, 0 is FALSE.  The authors haven't made it clear what they are trying to represent.  You need to contact the authors and ask them for further details.

Comment: Alright. No worries. Thank you so much for helping out though.

Answer (score 0):

The full paper which can be found at http://www.iam.fmph.uniba.sk/ospm/Filova/surv/nwtco_paper.pdf says that the two columns represent favorable (=1) and unfavorable (=2) determinations on the part of the pathologist at the treating and the central pathology laboratories. If you follow one of the other Google-identified references you can find some code (from http://search.r-project.org/library/cchs/html/cchsData.html) that labels the numeric values:

```
cchsData <- data.frame(
   id = nwtco$seqno, 
   localHistol = factor(nwtco$instit, labels=c("favorable", "unfavorable")), 
   centralLabHistol = factor(nwtco$histol, labels=c("favorable", "unfavorable")), 
   stage = factor(nwtco$stage, labels=c("I", "II", "III", "IV")), 
   study = factor(nwtco$study, labels=c("NWTS-3", "NWTS-4")),
   isCase = as.logical(nwtco$rel), 
   time = nwtco$edrel,
   ageAtDiagnosis = nwtco$age / 12  # nwtco$age is in months
```